# Can't execute command using Chef

Tags: jboss, automation, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using chef to automate deployment. In that Starting of jboss is needed so I used this code to start it.

```
bash "jboss_checking" do
  code <<-EOL
     JBOSS_DIR='/home/Documents/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final'
     cd $JBOSS_DIR
     nohup ./bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &
  EOL
end
```

when I run this script jboss not going to start.When i put the same commands in .sh file and run it, jboss started. Can anybody suggest me where I need to change?

I find out new way.If I remove '&' from this line

"nohup ./bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &"

JBOSS is running but it paused chef script to continue.

Comment: You probably have an environment problem when running this command from chef. (I would bet on the JAVA_HOMe env var not being set)

Comment: I find out new way.If I remove '&' from this line nohup ./bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &

Comment: Didn't noticed you used a & to detach from parent and nohup which serve the same purpose... I wonder how nohup behaves in this case, but it probably ends as there's nothing to detach

Comment: I think nohup will redirect output to nohup.out and '&' will seperate from parent

Comment: The main purpose of nohup is to make the process immune to kill -HUP (when the tty is closed and parent killed for exemple) Detaching from parent achieve this same goal, but is less resilient and don't manage output.

Comment: I got this from nohup manual :       `nohup' does not automatically put the command it runs in the
background; you must do that explicitly, by ending the command line
with an `&'.  Also, `nohup' does not alter the niceness of COMMAND; use
`nice' for that, e.g., `nohup nice COMMAND'.

Comment: Which distribution are you using ?

Comment: I'll had to recheck this in this case. Anyway, you should use a init or upstart script and a service resource in chef instead of starting from a bash resource. I think there's a jboss cookbook existing which could be a good starting point. You may run chef with `-l debug` too to see where the bash resource fail (or if it print out something)

Comment: I got it by redirecting output to some file "nohup ./bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &" > outputfile

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it this way:

```
bash 'jboss_checking' do
  code <<-EOL
    nohup ./bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 &
  EOL
  user '...username...'
  cwd '/home/Documents/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final'
  environment(
    'JAVA_HOME' => '...'
  )
end
```

which

- specifies working directoy explicitly
- defines the user under which the command is executed
- as Tensibai already said: You'll need to specify at least JAVA_HOME and probably other environment variables, too.

An even better solution would be to deploy an sysv-init/upstart/systemd/launchd script…

Comment: I have added this script by replacing java_home path and username.It is giving this error :FATAL: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::JAVA_HOME